# python iterator outputs in a abnormal order

Tags: python-3.5

In Python 3.5x executed the below code

```
for key in {'six':-99, 'one':1, '1.5': 1.5, 'two':2, 'five':5}:
    print(key)
```

I was expecting the output in the below order

- six, one,
  1.5, two, five

and got the below output

- 1.5, six, five, two, one

Why this weird behaviour, that too without requesting to change the order, also why this random order ?

you can try at the below link

[Run Code](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=for%20key%20in%20%7B'six'%3A-99,%20'one'%3A1,%20'1.5'%3A%201.5,%20'two'%3A2,%20'five'%3A5%7D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28key%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=11&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary)